# What plant is this? Not sure whether this is a weed or a ground cover plant

Tags: identification

Any idea what this plant is? I started seeing these growing only this year in one part of our yard.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some kind of speedwell, and and I would consider it a weed if it was on on near my lawn, flower beds, or vegetable garden. It's an annual and can be picked out beds easily, but it's more difficult in lawns, without using weedkiller at least.